# Как в данном случае прям из функции присвоить значения переменным?

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T swap(T& a, T& b) {
    T* t = new T;
    *t = a;
    a = b;
    b = *t;
    delete t;
    return a, b;
}

int main() {
    int q = 1;
    int w = 3;
    double e = 2.3; 
    double t = 4.3;

    swap<int>(q, w);
    swap<double>(e, t);

    std::cout << q << " " << w << std::endl;
    std::cout << e << " " << t << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: А вот в GNU (g++) можно было бы использовать простой макрос `#define SWAP(a, b) ({__typeof__(a) t = b; b = a; a = t;})`, автоматически настраивающийся на типы переменных.

Comment: вы уже всё присвоили. что не получается у вас?

Comment: @AlexGlebe вроде кажется что да, но значения в функции должны меняться, а они не меняются) и я вот не понимаю почему...

Comment: меняются : https://godbolt.org/z/E4cYbTvfc

Comment: 1. `return a, b;` - это то же самое, что просто `return b;`. Но непонятно, зачем он вообще нужен. Уберите его, и замените возвращаемый тип на `void`. 2. `new` - это продвинутая вещь для особых случаев. Тут он не нужен. Просто сделайте `T t = a;`, и т.д.

Comment: @AlexGlebe странно... а почему тогда в визуал студио не меняются?

Comment: Что значит "не меняются"? Как вы это определили?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо большое! мне это помогло) и "не меняются" в том смысле, что они выводят те же значения что и были им присвоены изначально! а в функции они должны поменяться значениями)

Comment: 1. Ретон может вернуть только что-то одно. 2. Свап должен возращать воид. 3. А нафига здесь куча?

Answer (score 1):

Все работает (проверено именно в VC++), но не проще было бы просто написать

```
void swap(auto& a, auto& b) {
    auto t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

заодно не выделяя память динамически?

И - зачем вам это `return a, b;`? Кстати, надеюсь, вы в курсе, что при этом возвращается одно значение - `b`?

P.S. По обсуждении с HolyBlackCat родился более строгий вариант, не допускающий переменные разных типов:

```
void swap(auto& a, auto& b)
{
    static_assert(is_same_v<remove_cvref_t<decltype(a)>,
                            remove_cvref_t<decltype(b)>>,
                  "Different types");
    auto t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

Comment: ооо хорошо, запомню! но тут у меня дз сделать именно через template...)

Comment: Такой вариант может принять два разных типа, поэтому я бы оставил обычный шаблон.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, об этом я не подумал...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А как насчет варианта `void swap(auto& a, decltype(a)& b) {`?

Comment: Одинаково фигня. `swap(1, 1.f)` выдаст `int`, а `swap(1.f, 1)` выдаст `float`. В выводе шаблонного аргумента участвует только первый аргумент.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я все же хочу как-то без шаблонов добиться, пусть и левой рукой правое ухо... А `void swap(auto& a, auto& b) {
    static_assert(typeid(a) == typeid(b));`? Тут есть неприятности?

Comment: Только `std::is_same_v`, а то ваше условие не constexpr до C++23. И наверное лучше `requires`, чтобы SFINAE нормально работал. А так в целом нормально. Есть небольшая разница с обычным шаблоном (там `int a, b; std::swap(a, {b});` работает, а у вас нет), но выглядит ок.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `requires` же требует шаблонов, нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Тогда уж, чтоб ничего не снилось — `static_assert(is_same_v<remove_cvref_t<decltype(a)>,remove_cvref_t<decltype(b)>>);` Хотя, конечно, срывание того же `const` явно излишне. Но поскольку все это никак не влияет на эффективность кода — пуркуа бы и не па? И, кстати, у меня в VC++ `std::swap(a,{b})` не работает.